# Philosophical feminism and logic

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-logic, feminism

Are there any resources to study about academic works on philosophical feminism and logic?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. One-line posts are discouraged because it is hard to tell from them what people are looking for. Philosophical feminism and logic are each vast topics and without more context your question is too broad to be answered here. You can start by reading [SEP survey Feminist Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminist-philosophy/).

Comment: The question does seem very broad. Pick an author you already know and ask a question related to one of the author's texts. Eventually you will have the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I offer some suggestions. I expected to find a large amount of material, as there is for instance on philosophical feminism and epistemology. But philosophical feminism and logic offers much less. I have listed what I have found.

Comment: Since feminist philosophy tends to prefer informal logics, I think feminist epistemology, feminist ethics, the rationality of emotions, and criticisms of western norms of rationality should be some of the most relevant topics with a lot of work in them.

Comment: If a question is readable (what cannot be said of many "great" philosophers' works), and indeed have a valid and interesting answer, then why vote to close it? @Conifold "Philosophical feminism and logic are each vast topics" the OP is not questioning about them in separate, but works that mix both of them (on the contrary, `or` would be used instead of `and`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try :

Andrea Nye,  Words of Power: a feminist reading of the history of logic
(Routledge: London 1990).

Val Plumwood 'The Politics of Reason: Towards a Feminist Logic': Australasian Journal of Philosophy 71 (1993), pp. 436-462.

Allison Weir, Sacrificial Logics: Feminist Theory and the Critique of Identity, ISBN 10: 0415908639 / ISBN 13: 9780415908634
Published by Routledge, 1996.

These sources give bibliographical details of further work relevant to your interest.